# reCAPTCHA 2 causes 'too much recursion'

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, recaptcha

I am using bootstrap 4 in my Umbraco CMS project.

I want to add reCAPTCHA 2 in a registration form but I am having no luck with it.

Generated the keys for the recaptcha and set them in web.config where I can get later.

Here is my code of how I am trying to do it.

At the end of the header tag I included this scripts:

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Then the form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<AccountSurfaceController>("RegisterUser", null, new { id = "RegisterForm" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <small>Te gjitha fushat e meposhtme duhen plotesuar.</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="FirstName" class="form-control-label">Emri:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FirstName" id="FirstName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="LastName" class="form-control-label">Mbiemri:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LastName" id="LastName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Username" class="form-control-label">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" id="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email" class="form-control-label">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" id="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password" class="form-control-label">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" id="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control-label">Konfirmo Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="ConfirmPassword" id="ConfirmPassword">
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="captchaContainer" class="form-control-label">Captcha:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div id="captchaContainer" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[DictionaryKeys.ReCaptchaPublicKey]"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Regjistrohu</button>
}
```

I read some questions like this in SO but they did not solve my problem. 
The recaptcha item shows in the page but when I click on it it creates the error 'too much recursion' in console and shows nothing.

[image: Erro in the chrome]

Does anybody know why might cause this issue ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an issue with your form? Are you using does UmbracoForm function similar to FormValidation.io? I know you can get this error if your form is bad [link](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/#writing-form)

Comment: I have seen that too, but I am not using FormValidator at all, not sure what to look at my form actually, why there must be anything within the form that effects the recaptach ?

Comment: Can you tell which function/js file is triggering the overflow/too much recursion error? Is it from the `recaptcha/api.js`?

Comment: Yes its from recaptach__en.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and it was pretty strange indeed.

I had more than one form in my webpage.

The first one had the recaptcha while the other forms did not.
But other forms did have a field as below:

```
<input name="tagName" type="hidden" value="array" />
```

And that was the problem because when I change te name attribute to semthing else it works, for example:

```
<input  name="anotherName" type="hidden" value="array" />
```

I think there is a bug in recaptacha logic to handle this scenario if you put name attribute equal to tagName.

Anyway will report this to recaptach team and let know if this is a bug or there is something I am missing.